# CSS issue with drupal theme

Tags: css, drupal

I have created a drupal theme, URL: http://sundancefoundation.org/

There is a small shift in the layout when we switch between home page and about us page.

This is working fine in firefox only, all other browsers are showing this shift.

I know this is a CSS issue, but not able to fix it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The About us page is shorter than the screen height and therefor has no need for the scroll bar on the right hand side of the screen. The home page is longer and has a scroll bar. When the scroll bar appears or disappears it looks like the screen is shifting but that's all it is.

Comment: That's the only thing I see in Chrome/Mac. If this kind of shift is really a problem for you (hey, it's the web, these things happen), you can set a min-height on the body element. I would just live with it.

Comment: And by "you" I meant the original submitter, not SpaceBeers.

Answer (score 0):

This css rule will simple fix the body width flickering issue:

```css
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```